# Force Close: I have created a simple app with two fragments where fragemnt A is sendind data/string to Fragment B

Tags: android, android-fragments

As soon as app launches it throws **FORCE CLOSE**
**`LOGCAT` output**

```
04-04 02:52:19.070: W/dalvikvm(1149): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a93b90)
04-04 02:52:19.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1149): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 02:52:19.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1149): Process: com.example.twofrag, PID: 1149
04-04 02:52:19.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1149): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.twofrag/com.example.twofrag.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
04-04 02:52:19.090: E/AndroidRuntime(1149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)

04-04 03:18:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1294): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 03:18:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1294): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.twofrag/com.example.twofrag.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
04-04 03:18:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
04-04 03:18:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
04-04 03:18:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 03:18:13.190: E/AndroidRuntime(1294):     at com.example.twofrag.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
```

Interfcae class

```
public interface communicator {
    public void respond(String data);

}
```

`MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements communicator{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void respond(String data) {
        FragmentManager manger=getFragmentManager();
        FragB f2=(FragB) manger.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
        f2.changetext(data);

    }

}
```

> FagmentA

```
public class FragA extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    Button button;
    int counter=0;
    communicator com;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState==null)
        {
            counter=0;
        }
        else{
            counter=savedInstanceState.getInt("counter",0);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.id.layout_a, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        com=(communicator) getActivity();
        button=(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("counter", counter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        counter++;
        com.respond("the button "+counter+"times");
    }
}
```

> FragmentB

```
public class FragB extends Fragment{

    TextView textview;
    String data;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.id.layout_b, container, false);
        if(savedInstanceState==null)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            data=savedInstanceState.getString("text");
            TextView mytext=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            mytext.setText(data);

        }
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        textview=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("text", data);
    }
    public void changetext(String data){
        textview.setText(data);
        }
}
```

> ActivityMain.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.example.twofrag.FragA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.example.twofrag.FragB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fragment1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fragment1"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Fragment_a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#FFBB00"
    android:id="@+id/layout_a">

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Click ME" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> fragment_b.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#99cc00"
     android:id="@+id/layout_b">

    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml
added for landscape orientation

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.example.twofrag.FragA"
        android:layout_width="218dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.example.twofrag.FragB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That logcat is not complete, it should say the exception you are receiving after the error you are posting. Please check your logcat again and post it completely if you dont mind

Comment: I have updated logcat please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change from

```
inflater.inflate(R.id.layout_a);
inflater.inflate(R.id.layout_b);
```

to

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b);
```

in the onCreateView of your `FragA` and `FragB`.

you can always retrieve the view that represent the `Fragment` with `getView()`. Inside onActivityCreate change from `getActivity` to `getView`. Of course it makes only after `onCreateView` returns the View you inflated. Before `onCreateView` it returns null. On the other hand, I always suggest to use `onViewCreated`, when of course it is possibile, to perform all the `findViewById`. First parameter of  `onViewCreated` is the View you inflated and `onCreateView` returned

Comment: `textview=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1);` also wrong activity does not have textview in `onActivityCreated`

Comment: >"you can always retrieve the view that represent the Fragment with getView()" Actually not always, only **after** onCreateView returned non-null View and before onDestroyView returned.

Comment: I have added landscape orientation activity_main.xml.. but it is not getting displayed ..any idea about this problem .

Comment: Please find activity_main for landscape code in main thread/question

Comment: No...it still uses the same xml file...i mean it doesn't show in LANDSCAPE orientation

Comment: do you handle the orientation by your own?

Comment: I have not added/handled any code in main.java file.
I am in learning phase , this is my first fragment app